# Where to find tns.jar for Talend tOracleConnection

Tags: oracle, talend, tns

I am working on creating an Oracle connection in Talend. 
When I configure the tOracleConnection component, I install the prompted ojdbc.jar with no issues.
When I start to use this connection it shows an error message saying that tns.jar is required to run this component.
I have searched all popular repositories for this Jar but its not available. How can we work around this in Talend. I am using Talend Open Studio version for BigData 6.3.0.

[image: high level error]
[image: download greyed out]

Comment: You have to download the jar and copy that in your lib folder

Comment: can you please share the link for downloading the jar

Comment: Seems like talend support is down for maintenance

Comment: @Rakesh, You can click on the 'Install' button at the place where the warning is displayed. A window pops up to download and install and it will install the needed jar.

Comment: It does for sure, but its for uploading the jar from local disk

Comment: I went to the effort of downloading oracleXe server - the required JAR is not included there either.

Comment: Hovering over the "Action" icon in Talend Third Party Module window shows the Maven link it is trying to download:   

mvn:org.talend.libraries/tns/6.0.0/jar   

which doesn't seem to be in the Maven Central Repository.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should be able to download it from Talend Forge but its down at the moment. I am also looking for it but it doesnt seem to be available for download anywhere else unfortunately.

I spoke to our contact at Talend and they are working hard to get TF up again, hopefully today.

Answer (score 0):

Hovering over the "Action" icon in Talend Third Party Module window shows the Maven link it is trying to download: mvn:org.talend.libraries/tns/6.0.0/jar which doesn't seem to be in the Maven Central Repository.

I have tried looking at other components in Talend and I get the same problem, so its not just tns Jar file.

As Andreas has mentioned, the Talend site is currently down, which appears to be a single point of failure unfortunately!

The Solution will be to wait until [this](https://talend-update.talend.com/nexus/content/repositories/libraries/org/talend/libraries/) site is back up.

[image: Talend Site Down]

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what specific version it is asking for but did you try downloading jar from java2s.com ? I have downloaded many a times jar from this website, never faced any issue. Below is the link for tns.jar:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/t/Downloadtnsconfig21010jar.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Talend Open Studio for Big Data Version: 8.0.1 and I have same issue, you can download the missing library from this link https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html

file name: ojdbc8.jar

then you can browse it on **Action** field and choose it. the issue should be resolve.